# Zoom MKMapView to CLRegion

Tags: iphone, ios5, mkmapview

I am getting a CLPlacemark using the CLGeocoder on iOS5. Now I would like to take the region (CLRegion object) of a placemark and have my MKMapView zoom to that region, how on earth is this possible?

I want the inverse of [this](https://gist.github.com/3402711), but there seems to be no `-locationFromLocationWithDistance:` or equivalent method. I'm hoping nobody says you have to use the Haversine formula in reverse because that looks a tad complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the mathematics provided [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). And for the code

```
        CLLocationCoordinate2D center = placemark.location.coordinate;
        CLRegion* coreLocationRegion = placemark.region;
        CLLocationDistance radius = coreLocationRegion.radius;
#define kBEARING_NORTH 0.0
#define kBEARING_EAST  .5 * M_PI
#define kBEARING_SOUTH M_PI
#define kBEARING_WEST  1.5 * M_PI

#define kEARTH_RADIUS_M 6371000.0

        // Store the angular distance of each side from the center
        double angDist = radius / kEARTH_RADIUS_M;

        // Convert center lat and lng to radians
        double centerLatRad =  center.latitude * M_PI / 180;
        double centerLngRad = center.longitude * M_PI / 180;

        // Calculate latitude range
        double maxLatRad = asin(sin(centerLatRad) * cos(angDist) +
                                cos(centerLatRad) * sin(angDist) * cos(kBEARING_NORTH));

        double minLatRad = asin(sin(centerLatRad) * cos(angDist) +
                                cos(centerLatRad) * sin(angDist) * cos(kBEARING_SOUTH));

        // Calculate longitude range
        // Longitude range requires coresponding latitudes:
        double tempLatRad;

        // Calculate max longitude
        tempLatRad = asin(sin(centerLatRad) * cos(angDist) +
                          cos(centerLatRad) * sin(angDist) * cos(kBEARING_EAST));

        double maxLngRad = centerLngRad + atan2(sin(kBEARING_EAST) * sin(angDist) * cos(centerLatRad),
                                                cos(angDist) - sin(centerLatRad) * sin(tempLatRad));

        // Calculate min longitude
        tempLatRad = asin(sin(centerLatRad) * cos(angDist) +
                          cos(centerLatRad) * sin(angDist) * cos(kBEARING_WEST));

        double minLngRad = centerLngRad + atan2(sin(kBEARING_WEST) * sin(angDist) * cos(centerLatRad),
                                                cos(angDist) - sin(centerLatRad) * sin(tempLatRad));

        CLLocationDegrees latitudeDelta = (maxLatRad-minLatRad) * 180 / M_PI;
        CLLocationDegrees longitudeDelta = (maxLngRad-minLngRad) * 180 / M_PI;
        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta);
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
        [self.mapView setRegion: region animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

Or, instead of all that math, just use the methods provided for this by the API.

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([placemark region].center, [placemark region].radius, [placemark region].radius);
[[self mapView] setCenterCoordinate:[placemark region].center animated:NO];
```

Comment: The CLRegion.radius is in meters and MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance accepts latitude/longitude. That's why all that math is needed I believe.

Comment: Not coordinates, spans: MKCoordinateRegion MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
   CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate,
   CLLocationDistance latitudinalMeters,
   CLLocationDistance longitudinalMeters
);

Comment: Hi @quellish, though its late response, I would like to ask u , I have tried this, its working fine some countries, for some countries like United States, Bermuda, Saudi, Palestine... its not coming, for united states, the map is moving to right corner...

Comment: Why do you go to the effort of calculating a region and just use its center?