# iOS 7 - region.center deprecated

Tags: ios, maps, ios7

I have this code for my iOS app:

```
NSString *location = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [self.campus campusStreetAddress], [self.campus campusCityStateZip]];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
                     MKCoordinateRegion region = self.campusMap.region;
                     region.center = placemark.region.center; //DEPRECATED iOS 7
                     region.span.longitudeDelta /= 1500;
                     region.span.latitudeDelta /= 1500;
                     [self.campusMap setRegion:region animated:NO];
                     [self.campusMap addAnnotation:placemark];
                 }
             }
 ];
```

But, when I upgraded my app to iOS 7, placemark.region.center is deprecated. Is there a replacement I should use? Is this even a proper method to creating a map in a view?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];
```

Comment: The only thing that troubles me about this solution is that there is no guarantee that CLPlacemark's region property is necessarily always going to be a CLCircularRegion. It probably works for now, but... I think I'd prefer to confirm that the region is a CLCircularRegion before using its center property, and find an acceptable alternative value if not.

Comment: I agree with @DougKnowles isn't there now a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 8):

if you just want the center of the region you can use :

> region.center = placemark.location.coordinate

Comment: Actually I get diff latitude/longitude answers when I use placemark center and when I use location coordinates.

let center = (placemarks?[0].region as! CLCircularRegion).center
print(placemarks?[0].location?.coordinate ?? "???")

The diff is large enough to produce different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of Heesien's and [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13451882/296446) and a bit of experimenting.

```
- (void)centerMapAroundPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    CLRegion *region = placemark.region;

    if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLCircularRegion class]])
    {
        [self centerMapAroundCircularRegion:(CLCircularRegion *)region
                            centerCoodinate:placemark.location.coordinate];
    }
    else
    {
        [self centerMapAroundCoorinate:placemark.location.coordinate];
    }
}

- (void)centerMapAroundCircularRegion:(CLCircularRegion *)circularRegion
{
    MKCoordinateRegion coordinateRegion =
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(circularRegion.center,
                                       circularRegion.radius,
                                       circularRegion.radius);

    [self.mapView setRegion:coordinateRegion animated:YES];
}

- (void)centerMapAroundCircularRegion:(CLCircularRegion *)circularRegion
                      centerCoodinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)centerCoodinate
{
    // Only user the radius of region for an appropriate zoom level.
    // The center of the region is not accurate.
    // To see this search for 'Bath, UK'

    MKCoordinateRegion coordinateRegion =
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centerCoodinate,
                                       circularRegion.radius,
                                       circularRegion.radius);

    [self.mapView setRegion:coordinateRegion animated:YES];
}
```